# Wordpress is ignoring my custom Archive template for CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom post type called `video` and custom taxonomy acting as categories called `video_category`

I want to create a custom archive page for the video categories. So I created a new file called `archive-video.php` and placed a simple `h1` tag inside.

But whenever I visit `/video_category/category/` it get the default archive template and in there, I see the posts associated with the custom taxonomy but posts from the default `post` type as well and it displays the categories of the `post` type instead of the custom taxonomy.

in `functions.php`

```
function video_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Videos', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Video', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Videos', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Add into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Video', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Videos', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'comments' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'video_category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-video-alt2',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'video', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'video_post_type', 0 );

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function video_category_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Categories', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'has_archive'                => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'video_category', array( 'video' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'video_category_taxonomy', 0 );
```

This is `archive-video.php`

```
<?php

get_header();

?>

    <h1>Video Archive</h1>

<?php

get_footer();
```

Comment: can you check after update permalink from admin section?

Comment: That's the first thing I did, no dice.

Comment: do you retun 404 error?

Comment: No, the page loads and it displays posts.

Comment: Try only `/video/` in url it works in my system Also Save Permalink as "Post Name".

Comment: I can see the archive template when I visit `/video/` but how can I apply it to the custom taxonomy instead?

Comment: For That you have to Generate rewrite rules as like this [https://codeable.io/get-your-custom-taxonomy-urls-in-order/]

Answer (score 0):

can you try below code into function.php file.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
    if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        if($post_type) {
            $post_type = $post_type;
        } else {
            $post_type = array('post','video'); // replace CPT to your custom post type
        }
        $query->set('post_type',$post_type);

    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Comment: chnage, 
'taxonomies'            => array( 'video_category', 'post_tag' ),
to
'taxonomies'            => array( 'video_category' ),

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the WordPress docs for [Custom Taxonomy template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies).

It looks like you're using the custom post-type archive by using `archive-{post_type).php` for `archive-video.php`. If you want to create a template for the `video_category` custom taxonomy you'll need to create a file called `taxonomy-video_category.php`.

---

Also, I found out that it you are using the [WPML](https://wpml.org/) plugin for translation, if you do not set your custom taxonomy as translatable in the plugin settings, your `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` template will get ignored.